# No puedo acceder a wordpress local desde Smartphone (Error Connection Refused)

Tags: wordpress, xampp

He instalado una copia de mi sitio web en localhost (uso xampp para Windows) para poder realizar pruebas con él.

Todo va bien... Hasta que quiero acceder desde otro dispositivo ubicado en la misma red local (en este caso desde mi smartphone)

El problema es el siguiente:

- Tecleo la IP del equipo donde tengo alojada la copia de la web seguida de la ruta: 192.168.1.36/copiasitioweb
- El navegador cambia la IP por "localhost" y me devuelve un "Error Connection Refused"
- Esto solo sucede con la copia del sitio web wordpress que tengo en local, a mis demás proyectos puedo acceder sin problema.

¿A que puede deberse esto? ¿Permisos? ¿Alguna configuración errónea en los archivos de configuración de Wordpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede ser debido a la configuración guardada en la base de datos.
Revisa la tabla **wp_options** o si pusiste algún prefijo de tabla distinto a wp sería **prefijo_options**.

Ahí revisa las columnas **option_name** y **option_value**, en la columna option_name revisa los valores de **siteurl** y **home**, si los valores de estas están con localhost, cambia localhost por la ip de la maquina que esta corriendo el servidor. Por ejemplo:

[image: Localhost]

[image: Cambio Localhost por IP]

Comment: Hola Juan, muchísimas gracias por contestar. He hecho lo que dices y funciona, ya puedo acceder desde el smartphone. Muestra todo menos las imágenes, ¿A que puede deberse? ¿Ajustes de enlaces, quizás?

Comment: Si, es que al momento de cambiar esos valores desde la db no se actualizan los enlaces de la imagenes, eso te toca cambiar manualmente o puedes instalar una extensión para hacerlo automáticamente yo generalmente uso la siguiente extensión para actualizar los urls: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Comment: Prueba a actualizar los enlaces permanentes Ajustes>Enlaces permanentes. Alli cambias la opción de los mismos y guardas y luego la vuelves a poner como estaba y guardas. de esa manera se renuevan las direcciones.