# Ver localmente mi pagina web desde Teléfono Error

Tags: wordpress, xampp, localhost

Disculpen, Quiero ver mi Pagina web localmente (Utilizo Xampp), utilizo la misma red de internet para mi pc y teléfono, y agrego la dirección  192.168.1.150 en mi telefono (lo veo utilizando el cmd con el comando ipconfig), y si me permite visualizar la pagina principal de xampp por asi decirlo, pero al momento de querer ver mi pagina  192.168.1.150/wordpress este me dice conexión rechazada.
¿Alguno me podría decir porque me pasa eso?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta necesita mucho más detalle para poder determinar el problema, por ejemplo, ¿están abiertos los puertos adecuados en la interfaz de red de tu servidor?. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega todo lo que haga falta. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: verifica que wordpress esté instalado en la ip y no en `localhost`  (con el cli `wp option get siteurl`) ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8030/81450 para un quick fix en la db. puede que necesites refrescar los "enlaces permanentes" otra forma de cambiarlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151372/81450